# How to sign an android app for the market?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play, signing

I've recently released my first app on the market. I tried to install the app on my phone immediately after it was released. But when installing it I got an error saying that the app was wrongly signed. I also got lots of bad ratings for my app because other people couldn't install it as well.

So my question is: how can I sign my app correctly? Is there any way to test the result before releasing the app on the market?

BTW: I used the built in function of eclipse to export the signed apk file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to create  Release Key for Signing your Application.

Step : 1 Right Click Project->Export Application->Select you Project->Next->Select new Keystore -> Complete all rest Steps

Step : 2 Note down your **Alias** name and **Password** given.

Step : 3 Now if you Complete all process of Filling Details you will get one **.apk file** and **keystore file** in you stored location.

Step : 4 Now Again Right Click Project->Export Application->Select you Project->Next->Use Existing Keystore -> Give location and password->Next

Step : 5 Now you alias name will comes in your Drop Down->Select it -> Enter Password -> Next

Step : 6 It will ask for location to store your final .apk file.

Step : 7 Select your location and store.

Step : 8 Now this **Final .apk** file is Your Signed Application.

Note : Keep this **keystore file** for further updated of your Application in Android Market ,also keep track of your Alias name and Password

Comment: What's a Google Maps key got to do with Android app signing?

Comment: most people use a API that is signed with their debug.keystore.  Most people that sign are not using the debugkeystore any longer.. so I think the Google API key won't matchup any longer.

Answer (score 1):

We can't really tell you from afar what is wrong. Did you create your own self-signed certificate? The cert that comes with SDK is a debug certificate and should not be used for signing a production app.

I recommend you thoroughly read the docs about [signing the apps](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html).