# Couldn't get connection factory client - fighting with Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

another day another problem, I finally managed to set up correctly google maps on my android application, or at least I thought I've done it, the whole progam starts, it even call the class which should "print" a map, but the only thing I can see is a grid with google label on it [ in the corner ]. I've checked the dalvik monitor and the error

> E/MapActivity(394): Couldn't get connection factory client

occurs. I've find out on stackoverflow website that I should sent a gps signal or sth like this from dalvik monitor, and I've done it. Nothing happend, also I got the api key one more time, but nothing changed.

here is map.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- This file is /res/layout/mapview.xml -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<Button android:id="@+id/zoomin" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="+"
android:onClick="myClickHandler"
android:padding="12px" />
<Button android:id="@+id/zoomout" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="-"
android:onClick="myClickHandler" 
android:padding="12px" />
<Button android:id="@+id/sat" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="Satellite"
android:onClick="myClickHandler" 
android:padding="8px" />
<Button android:id="@+id/street" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="Street"
android:onClick="myClickHandler" 
android:padding="8px" />
<Button android:id="@+id/traffic" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="Traffic"
android:onClick="myClickHandler" 
android:padding="8px" />
<Button android:id="@+id/normal" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="Normal"
android:onClick="myClickHandler" 
android:padding="8px" />
</LinearLayout>
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
android:id="@+id/mapview" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:clickable="true"
android:apiKey="0zPcz1VYRSpLusufJ2JoL0ffl2uxDMovgpW319w" />
</LinearLayout>
```

here is a MapMapa.java

```
public class MapMapa extends MapActivity
{
private MapView mapView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.map);
mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapview);
}

public void myClickHandler(View target) {
switch(target.getId()) {
case R.id.zoomin:
mapView.getController().zoomIn();
break;
case R.id.zoomout:
mapView.getController().zoomOut();
break;
case R.id.sat:
mapView.setSatellite(true);
break;
case R.id.street:
mapView.setStreetView(true);
break;
case R.id.traffic:
mapView.setTraffic(true);
break;
case R.id.normal:
mapView.setSatellite(false);
mapView.setStreetView(false);
mapView.setTraffic(false);
break;
}
}
@Override
protected boolean isLocationDisplayed() {
return false;
}
@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
return false;
}
```

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="menu.dot" android:versionCode="1" ndroid:versionName="1.0">
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
<activity android:name="MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>

</activity>
<activity android:name=".About">
android:label="@string/about_title" 
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
</activity>
<activity android:name=".Exit">
andorid:label="@string/exit_title"> 
</activity>
<activity android:name=".Options">
</activity>
<activity android:name=".Start">
</activity>
<activity android:name=".Create">
</activity>
<activity android:name=".Where">
</activity>
<activity android:name=".Proceed">
</activity>
<activity android:name=".Finish">
</activity>
<activity android:name=".Login">
</activity>
<activity android:name=".OK">
</activity>
<activity android:name=".UserPanel">
</activity>
<activity android:name=".Managero">
</activity>
<activity android:name=".Edition">
</activity>
<activity android:name=".Done">
</activity>
<activity android:name=".Delete">
</activity>
<activity android:name=".MapMapa">
</activity>

</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
</manifest>
```

[image: my view]

Comment: not sure if this would cause that problem but, have you set the internet permission in the android manifest file?

Comment: @user552629 Post your Manifest file?

Comment: Kurtis Nusbaum, didn't know that I've corrected my mistake ;)

Comment: @lie you map is not shown you check youe api key and then see your map..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
E/MapActivity(394): Couldn't get connection factory client
```

This will not be issue in your case. It's just warning message.

For using Map,things you need to Keep in mind :

1.Add internet permission in Manifest file

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

2.Add Library code in Manifest file :

```
 <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

3. Extend `Map Activity` instead of Activity also ensure that your **SDK** is **Google** not Android
4. Then generate Map Key using `Release Key` and not by using `Default Android Debug key`
   Check this post for creating [Key using Release Key.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7728460/how-to-sign-an-android-app-for-the-market/7728587#comment9403046_7728587)

For further references check this link [Mobi Forge](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android)

[image: Output of your code]

Comment: hmm I've done this thing to get the key from google [ this md5 ] keystore etc. Do I have to make this release key even for emulator?

Comment: @iie No not needed for Emulator?

Comment: so yes or no? I've done this signing thing, but nothing changed

Comment: hell... which lvl api r u using?

Comment: maybe this is the reason, I'm using 2.2

Comment: @iie Try to create sample New Project and try it.. That's your last option.. I am sure there is no pblm in your code.

Comment: check my post to see what I have

Comment: is there a chance that it isn't working because of my api key?

Comment: @iie You are running in Device or Emulator?

Comment: Does this mean we can only use release key for signing? According to most of the tutorials, we can use the debug key, but I can't still make it work. I've used the debug key

Answer (score 1):

you need to build signed apk file, try with that in your mobile. I passed same problem

Answer (score 1):

In Android Map Program you have to put  following permission in Android Manifest file
**before** 
`<application></application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

and you should write **in  tag and before**

`<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />`

and Generate proper map api key...
After that i face problem .
Than I create new Android project with Google Api... I solved the problem...

Answer (score 0):

dude, how do you get the api key ?
if the debug.keystore is located in ur documents and settings, probably you will need to copy  keytool.exe so you can execute
keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keys
tore debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android -v

this will release a wrong MD5 key. you have to do the following
1- copy your debug.keystore to your program files java  bin 
2-go to this directory in cmd and execute the keytool command
it will give you a different MD5 and this is the right one.

Answer (score 0):

[You need this chk your apikey](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/mapkey)

You make you api key and when you change your eclipse you also use your keystorke..