# Map Activity Android

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, mapactivity

I have problem displaying a map on the emulator and device.

When I run the code it seems okay and all I got is plain grid display and on the logCat I have error `Couldn’t get connection factory client`

Is it do with the keystore API? Can I use same API key for other map activity that I implemented? or does it has to be unique?

Thanks.

Comment: the API key is generated with the combination of your gmail account and your machine. So you can use same API key in you system for multiple projects, if your project is on another machine you have to change the API key.

Answer (score 1):

Its a best tutorial for starting with Map

http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android

Comment: Thanks but I tried all the suggestions by getting a new API key using commond prompt:
`...........android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android` but still it gave me an error: "Couldn't get connection factory client! :(

Comment: just ignore this error it would not affect showing your map. if you have correct API key then surely you will get the map instead of grid

Answer (score 0):

you can use same key but key verise with signing key so it would be different for device and emulator as if signing key is different..

and see

[Couldn't get connection factory client - fighting with Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982320/couldnt-get-connection-factory-client-fighting-with-google-maps)

Answer (score 0):

Yes proble is with your API_KEY.
You must have to generate key as per your package name.
Refer this link:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2