# android map application is working on emulator but not on device

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator

I have developed an android map application in eclipse and tested it on emulator it works on emulator fine but when i tested it no device then markers are shown but map is not loading only blank tiles are showing . Please help me to get out of this issue.

Comment: Are you using the same debug key to sign on your device? if not.. you have to change the api key to one that is generated with your signing key.

Comment: Yes I have Generated a new api key from new fingerprint and uploaded to Google Play i will test it from that and accept your answer later

Comment: [Steps to be followed for creating Release Key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982320/couldnt-get-connection-factory-client-fighting-with-google-maps/7982578#7982578)

Comment: Thanks for Reply but Will My issue Be resolved by using new api with new fingerprint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a different key to sign the application for your mobile, you need to generate a new MD5 fingerprint from that key and generate a new map api key for your application

[Obtaining a Google Maps Android API Key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey)

Comment: I Have already Generated the New MD5 FingerPrint and then Generated a new api key and replace this in main.xml and then run the application in emulator it works fine but when i exported as apk and uploaded to Gooogle play and then on my android device it don't shown the map except blank tiles.So What may be the issue now and what can i do now?

Comment: The key using when you run the emulator is the debug key.. when you upload to Google Play is a different key.. so check that the MD5 fingerprint is the one for the release key.

Comment: Sir I don't know difference between debug key and release key please tell me how uninstall the debug key and the to intall the release key

Comment: @user1505962 have a look at this: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#cert there's an example of how to generate a new key for Google Play.

Comment: Sir I have run jarsigner but this is error : 
jarsigner: unable to open jar file: Track.apk  
What may be the issue

Comment: Have you tried the example in the link I posted before? `jarsigner -verbose -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore
my_application.apk alias_name` where you have to change `my-release-key.keystore`, `my_application.apk`  `alias_name` with the values that suits for you

Comment: Sir I have run the same command as link provided but when i run this command this error shows.I want to ask where to place the apk file when we export app as unsigned from eclips

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin>jarsigner -verbose -sigalg MD5withRSA -dig
estalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore Track.apk Maps 


Sir I am running this command and the error is above only tell me where to place the apk when we export the application as unsigned package

Comment: You need to specify the full path of your apk `C:\Android\apk\Track.apk` (for example) or put the apk inside `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin`

Comment: Sir Thanks For Help  i have completed the all steps now i am going to test it on my android device then i tell u the status

Comment: Sir Sorry to say that application run on android device again shown up the blank tiles not shown up the map

Comment: When you created the MD5 fingerprint, did you use the `my-release-key.keystore` or the `debug.keystore`?

Comment: Sir I did'nt created MD5 again

Comment: Sir did u mean i have to create new api using my-release-key and then paste it into existing api ???

Comment: Exactly.. you need to update the layout with the new api key generated from that keystore.

Comment: after that how will it exported as unisigned or anyohter way ?