# Couldn't get connection factory client. API key is working

Tags: android

I am trying to implement a simple maps application in Android. So far I made sure I have the correct API key and a simple map actually shows up on the screen. I can even control the zoom level and see the effects. But I cant do anything else such as a basic operation as setCenter().

```
My LogCat gives the error : "Couldn't get connection factory client"
```

What should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: are you testing in Emulator or in Device ??

Comment: on my own device. Runs android sdk 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem in my particular situation. And its a dumb situation as I get it.

I still could not get rid of the "Couldn't get connection factory client" problem (in one of the sources I actually read stated that this message was a bug and should be ignored in most cases. Most of the time the problem is smthing else.)

My "actual" problem was simply putting in GeoPoints in wrong format. I first did it it like:

```
GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(19.2,-99.1);
```

and obviously it was wrong way of putting it. The numbers are expected to be bigger according to the documentation. So I used the following and it worked...

```
GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(19240000,-99120000);
```

Sorry for the misleading question. But I ll leave it here. Maybe smo else would have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

same problem when using getFromLocationName, with a 'java.io.IOException:Service not Available' error.

done a bit of googling around and it seems this is a bug in the software.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8816

[Android MapActivity : Couldn't get connection factory client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006835/android-mapactivity-couldnt-get-connection-factory-client)

[Couldn't get connection factory client - fighting with Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982320/couldnt-get-connection-factory-client-fighting-with-google-maps)

refered from [Couldn't get connection factory client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199403/couldnt-get-connection-factory-client)