# Getting Gray squares instead of Google map in my android app

Tags: java, android

I am on the way of creating a web based android application and I would like to integrate Google Map in my app. I got my api key also, but still I am getting the grey squares instead of the actual map.Also there is an error message that I have given below

In console I am getting this message

```
[2012-12-17 17:37:28 - Google] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.google/.MapsActivity }
[2012-12-17 17:37:28 - Google] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front
```

This is my logcat:

```
12-17 17:31:23.004: W/dalvikvm(301): threadid=1: spin on suspend #1 threadid=8 (pcf=0)
12-17 17:31:23.004: D/dalvikvm(301): Temporarily moving tid 313 to fg (was 0)
12-17 17:31:23.004: D/dalvikvm(301): Temporarily raised priority on tid 313 (19 -> 0)
12-17 17:31:23.013: W/dalvikvm(301): threadid=1: spin on suspend resolved in 1014 msec
12-17 17:31:23.013: D/dalvikvm(301): Restored policy of 313 to 0
12-17 17:31:23.013: D/dalvikvm(301): Restored priority on 313 to 19
12-17 17:31:23.444: D/dalvikvm(301): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 5064 objects / 310440 bytes in 1440ms
12-17 17:31:23.864: D/dalvikvm(301): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 9756 objects / 595416 bytes in 98ms
12-17 17:31:24.194: D/dalvikvm(301): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 5164 objects / 335976 bytes in 135ms
12-17 17:31:24.374: D/dalvikvm(301): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 6226 objects / 380088 bytes in 59ms
12-17 17:31:24.584: D/dalvikvm(301): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 8548 objects / 652784 bytes in 52ms
12-17 17:31:24.744: D/dalvikvm(301): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 6088 objects / 369232 bytes in 59ms
12-17 17:31:24.903: I/MapActivity(301): Handling network change notification:CONNECTED
12-17 17:31:24.903: E/MapActivity(301): Couldn't get connection factory client
12-17 17:31:28.734: D/dalvikvm(301): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 5901 objects / 533024 bytes in 47ms
12-17 17:31:31.524: D/dalvikvm(301): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1368 objects / 166224 bytes in 41ms
12-17 17:31:36.544: D/dalvikvm(301): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1278 objects / 162584 bytes in 41ms
12-17 17:31:39.044: D/dalvikvm(301): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1278 objects / 162552 bytes in 42ms
12-17 17:31:41.594: D/dalvikvm(301): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1278 objects / 162512 bytes in 42ms
12-17 17:31:54.893: D/dalvikvm(301): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1278 objects / 162568 bytes in 43ms
12-17 17:32:25.104: D/dalvikvm(301): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1278 objects / 162568 bytes in 41ms
12-17 17:33:35.694: D/dalvikvm(301): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1278 objects / 162504 bytes in 42ms
12-17 17:36:25.954: D/dalvikvm(301): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1280 objects / 162560 bytes in 40ms
```

Comment: "Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front" is shown when your application is already running and you try to run it again.

Comment: But even after I restarted eclipse also, I am getting the same error

Comment: Its not an error. Its just a 'warning' to tell you that you're trying to run the same app from eclipse and the code hasn't changed, so no compilation is done. You can ignore that.

Comment: Thank You, But could you please tell that Why I cannot access Google map, Now i am getting simple squares only in a gray background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, that's not an error and neither is linked with your problem.

You should check that you're following the guide of the [new Android Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/), also check that your api key is well written.

---

**EDIT**: You can also check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982320/couldnt-get-connection-factory-client-fighting-with-google-maps) for more info.

Comment: 12-17 17:31:24.903: I/MapActivity(301): Handling network change notification:CONNECTED
   12-17 17:31:24.903: E/MapActivity(301): Couldn't get connection factory client. These two lines confused me a little bit

Comment: These are ignorable too, I always get them when trying to invoke a Map in my apps.

Answer (score 0):

...or use a free library that does not need any API keys or other things: https://sourceforge.net/projects/libwlocate/ is lightweight, supports OSM, Google Maps, Google Sattelite, comes with full support for zooming/moving and an example implementation that demonstrates functionality.

Comment: The fact that you don't need to create a license, doesn't mean you're respecting the TOS