# How can i make my .apk signed for release in android

Tags: android, keystore, signed

I want to make the signed .apk's to release in the android market. 
Steps I followed are

1. Make a folder with name keys and save the .apk in that.
2. Then right click Project->android tools->export the signed .apk
3. Then follow all the instructions.

But when I click on the finish button after all the changes, it will give the error

```
java.io.IOExeption:Invalid key formate
```

Comment: I would follow these steps instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7728460/how-to-sign-an-android-app-for-the-market

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse, right click on the project then Android Tools -> Export Signed application package.

Then just create your own signature key, or use an existing one if you have it.